# DatafileManager: Error fetching datafile: Request error

Tags: optimizely

### Problem

I'm using Optimizely to code-gate my new website. But the allowed accounts aren't getting through. The first Firefox console error is

```
[OPTIMIZELY] - ERROR <timestamp> DatafileManager: Error fetching datafile: Request error
```

**How do I fix this error and fetch the data file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DatafileManager: Error fetching datafile: Request error

One of the network failures helped me out. The GET request for `cdn.optimizely.com` had "Blocked by AdBlocker Ultimate" in the Transferred column.

[image: One of the network failures helped me out. The GET request for cdn.optimizely.com had "Blocked by AdBlocker Ultimate" in the Transferred column.]

### Solution

I turned off AdBlocker Ultimate for this site.

If you encounter the `DatafileManager: Error fetching datafile: Request error` above, you may find out what's blocking Optimizely in your browser's Network requests.